# Why is there a difference between css property flex: 0 1 1 and flex: 0px 1 1

Tags: css, google-chrome, layout, syntax, flexbox

If I write some css property like `margin`, `padding` etc like below (in shorthand as well)

```
margin : 0 1px 0 1px; and margin : 0px 1px 0px 1px
```

The browser interprets both as 0 making no difference

```
'property: 0' or 'property: 0px' /* are same thing */
```

Why does it not applies for property `flex` in shorthand?

```
Name:   flex
Value:  none | [ <‘flex-grow’> <‘flex-shrink’> || <‘flex-basis’> ]
```

[**Demo 1** : using `flex: 0px 1 1` (works well)](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/kzbbb/3/)

[**Demo 2** : using `flex: 0 1 1` (doesn't works)](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/kzbbb/4/)

I also referred to http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/#flex-property , but found nothing that answers my doubt/issue.

Please help me understand if I am missing some point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only component of the `flex` shorthand that accepts a length as a value is `flex-basis`.

In the declaration `flex: 0px 1 1`, you're explicitly assigning one length value: `0px`. This will always be assigned to `flex-basis`. This declaration is equivalent to:

```
flex-basis: 0px;
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: 1;
```

The declaration `flex: 0 1 1`, on the other hand, is ambiguous, because `0` is a possible value of `flex-grow`. The first two values could potentially be assigned to `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` like so:

```
flex-grow: 0;
flex-shrink: 1;
```

But that leaves the last `1` value unitless, which is invalid CSS.

Now, you might ask why the parser couldn't just determine that `0` is the only value among the three that could be parsed into the length and behave accordingly. That is because the spec states (at the very end of that section):

> A unitless zero that is not already preceded by two flex factors must be interpreted as a flex factor. To avoid misinterpretation or invalid declarations, authors must specify a zero <‘flex-basis’> component with a unit or precede it by two flex factors.

This also resolves the ambiguity I mentioned earlier.

Comment: does it mean that `flex : 0px 1 1` , `flex : 1 0px 1` and `flex : 1 1 0px` are one and the same thing?

Comment: @Gaurav: Not all three of them. `1 0px 1` is invalid because `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` must appear together. You can have `flex-basis` either before or after the `<flex-grow> <flex-shrink>` pair, but not between them. That is what the `[ <‘flex-grow’> <‘flex-shrink’> || <‘flex-basis’> ]` notation in the spec means. The other two are indeed equivalent.

Comment: wait a second, I tried `flex : 1 0px 1`; http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/kzbbb/5/ it works well.

Comment: @Gaurav: Hmm, that's odd. The [Jigsaw validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator) does not report any problems either. Which browser are you testing in? On Firefox, the property fails - as I would expect it to. I'm going through the [test suite](http://test.csswg.org/harness/test/css-flexbox-1_dev/section/7.1) right now to see if there are any tests accounting for this.

Comment: I am testing it on latest Chrome.

Comment: I can confirm that "flex: 1 0px 1" has an effect in Chrome. That's definitely a bug. Mind reporting it at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry ?

Comment: Thanks! I CC'd some folks who may be able to take action on it.

Comment: @BoltClock : can you please edit my question giving the update about the bug reported so that I can accept this answer and close this question.