# IE 11 not aligning Flexbox properly

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

The following works fine with Chrome and FF

```
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction:column;">
    <div style="flex:1">
        Top<br />
        Top<br />
        Top<br />
        Top<br />
        Top<br />
        Top<br />
        Top<br />
        Top<br />
    </div>
    <div>Bottom</div>
</div>
```

However in IE 11, the Bottom DIV overlaps the top DIV. Any ways to fix this?

JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fwfA6/

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
flex: none | [ <'flex-grow'> <'flex-shrink'>? || <'flex-basis'> ]
```

This is the shorthand for `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis` combined. The second and third parameters (`flex-shrink` and `flex-basis`) are optional.

Default is 0 1 auto.

So change your style to (default for giving example, you can check with other values as well)

```
flex:0 1 auto
```

like

```
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction:column; min-height:100%">
    <div style="flex:0 1 auto">
        Top<br />
        Top<br />
        Top<br />
        Top<br />
        Top<br />
        Top<br />
        Top<br />
        Top<br />
    </div>
    <div style="flex:0 1 auto">Bottom</div>
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fwfA6/1/)**

---

From my question here [Why is there a difference between css property flex: 0 1 1 and flex: 0px 1 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032025/why-is-there-a-difference-between-css-property-flex-0-1-1-and-flex-0px-1-1)

I quote the Boltclock's answer

The only component of the `flex` shorthand that accepts a length as a value is `flex-basis`.

In the declaration `flex: 0px 1 1`, you're explicitly assigning one length value: `0px`. This will always be assigned to `flex-basis`. This declaration is equivalent to:

```
flex-basis: 0px;
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: 1;
```

The declaration `flex: 0 1 1`, on the other hand, is ambiguous, because `0` is a possible value of `flex-grow`. The first two values could potentially be assigned to `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` like so:

```
flex-grow: 0;
flex-shrink: 1;
```

But that leaves the last `1` value unitless, which is invalid CSS.

Now, you might ask why the parser couldn't just determine that `0` is the only value among the three that could be parsed into the length and behave accordingly. That is because the spec states (at the very end of that section):

> A unitless zero that is not already preceded by two flex factors must be interpreted as a flex factor. To avoid misinterpretation or invalid declarations, authors must specify a zero <‘flex-basis’> component with a unit or precede it by two flex factors.

This also resolves the ambiguity earlier.

Also read comments below to the question, Boltclock reported a bug to chrome https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=380984

Comment: The OP is setting `flex: 1`. That is in no way equivalent to the default. It's the same as `flex: 1 1 0%`. I am not sure how my answer to your question is at all relevant to this one.

Comment: @BoltClock setting it to default was just an example as I mentioned it in my answer. Your answer seemed relevant just because the explanation you gave their which dealt with the values of the flex, somewhere it may be a bug again.